# pip missing from python3.6 install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, pip, python3

I've installed python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 using:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
```

Unfortunately no `pip` is included. How have you solved this?

Comment: Did you install the `python3-pip` package? You normally need this to get pip.

Comment: that installs `python3-pip` for python 3.5.2 not 3.6 - no package exists for `python3.6-pip`

Comment: interestingly creating a virtualenv using `python3.6 -m venv my_venv` creates a `pip3.6` in the venv `bin` directory... not exactly what i wanted though

Comment: What about `python3.6 -m pip`?

Comment: oddly... not there. that was my original attempt...

Comment: I guess it's specific to that PPA; see if they have more details on it.

Comment: A simple solution: `add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on Stack Overflow. It consists of installing some more packages from the same ppa repo and then get pip from pypa.io. Optionnally, you might want to setup some links in order to have python3.6 be the default python3:

> Let's suppose that you have a system running Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10, or
>   17.04, and you want Python 3.6 to be the default Python.
>
> If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, you'll need to use a PPA:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6  # (only for 16.04 LTS)
> ```
>
> Then, run the following (this works out-of-the-box on 16.10 and
>   17.04):
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install python3.6
> sudo apt install python3.6-dev
> sudo apt install python3.6-venv
> wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
> sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3
>
> # Do this only if you want python3 to be the default Python
> # instead of python2 (may be dangerous, esp. before 2020):
> # sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python
> ```
>
> When you have completed all of the above, each of the following shell
>   commands should indicate `Python 3.6.1` (or a more recent version of
>   Python 3.6):
>
> ```
> python --version   # (this will reflect your choice, see above)
> python3 --version
> $(head -1 `which pip` | tail -c +3) --version
> $(head -1 `which pip3` | tail -c +3) --version
> ```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254088/3926735)